# QtCreator HTML5 link a javascript file from higher directory

Tags: javascript, html, qt-creator

In QtCreator, HTML5 application:

I would like to link a js file in a uncle directory.

Explanation: I tried to link a JS file in the same directory than `index.html` with

```
<script src="myjsfile.js" ></script>
```

And the link was ok, my js file was include.

But in my current application, the JS file is in higher level, and the `index.html` but this code:

```
<script src="../js/myjsfile.js" ></script>
```

Don't seem to work on my computer...

Here is my files structure:

```
 - Other files
    - html
       index.html
    - js
       entity.js
```

My entity.js file:

```
function hello() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

My index.html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="../js/entity.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="hello()">X</button>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

If someone could help me... [And if the question is stupid, please forgive me]